# Função dentro de JQuery qual a ordem de execução?

Tags: jquery, funções

Tenho uma função no jquery que possui um while que grava dados no banco de dados, e após este while ele imprime em console que os dados foram salvos, a função está assim:

```
function gravaDados(){
var qtde_linhas = 6 //ele pega a quantidade de linhas da tabela a ser salvo
var x = 1;
while( x <= qtde_linhas ) {

    ...//dados AJAX
    ... console.log('Dados gravados'); //salva os registros

x++;
}
console.log('dados salvos com sucesso '+x);
}
```

No console aparece que foram salvos os dados e a posição atual do x é 7 ou seja ele salvou as 6 linhas no banco, mas minha dúvida é a seguinte porque o `console.log` de dentro do `while` é impresso por ultimo?

[image: ele percorreu o while mas apresentou o utlimo console antes]

Como visto na imagem ele grava os dados mas imprime o console de forma inversa, isso é devido a demora de gravar os dados no banco, ou caso eu insira uma outra função no lugar do ultimo console posso ter problemas dos dados não terem sidos finalizados e executar a outra função? Por enquanto está funcionando, mas tenho essa dúvida, ou existe uma maneira dele checar se o while está finalizado para seguir com a estrutura?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso acontece provavelmente porque o `console` que está dentro do `while` está também dentro de uma `callback` do ajax, que é assíncrona.

Ou seja o código dispara os pedidos ajax para guardar no banco, sai do while e corre o `console` que está a seguir ao while. Mais tarde (ainda que apenas milisegundos) as respostas do banco começam a chegar e vão disparando os seus `console.log`.

Nestes casos é até possível que os console.log dentro do while cheguem com ordem trocada, ou seja não na sequência exata com que foram "disparados".

Comment: Muito obrigado por me tirar esta dúvida já havia lido algumas documentações mas nada que dizia com a clareza que você respondeu, creio que está resposta ajudará outras pessoas.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso fico contente de ter sido claro e útil.

Answer (score 3):

Porque a execução de códigos ajax, por padrão é assincrona, ou seja o jquery não vai aguardar o fim da execução da sua rotina para salvar os dados no banco antes de dar o console.log de "Dados salvos com sucesso".

Imagino que seja isso o seu problema.

Aqui tem uma expliação um pouco mais detalhada.
http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/requisicoes-sincronas-e-assincronas/

Comment: Boa explicação do link informado, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Wagner Fernando, outra coisa que não foi informado, é que a função primeiro não pode ter "-" (traço). Pode ficar assim por exemplo:

```
gravaDados()
```

E o `<=` também não pode ter espaço `< =`

```
function gravaDados(){
    var qtde_linhas = 6 //ele pega a quantidade de linhas da tabela a ser salvo
    var x = 1;
    while ( x <= qtde_linhas ) {
        console.log('Dados gravados'); //salva os registros
        x++;
    }
    console.log('dados salvos com sucesso '+x);
}
gravaDados();
```

Outra coisa é que não sei porque ele foi impresso por ultimo ai, mas aqui ele foi em ordem normal, com o código acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o código que coloquei na pergunta foi apenas para exemplificar meu problema, mas dentro do meu while existe um ajax que salva os dados que pela as respostas do Sérgio e Léo Nogueira é o motivo da impressão ter algum tempo para aparecer.

Comment: Pode por então essa explicação na sua pergunta la, editando. Ai fica mais claro pras pessoas que também tiverem essa dúvida :D